# correct way to copy binary file to buffer in c

Tags: c, gcc, binary, fread

I'm trying to open a bin file an get its data into a buffer and copy the data from that buffer to a section that I made called .my_data.
When I do hexdump binfile.bin I see

```
   00000000 4455 e589 00bf 0000 e800 0000 00b8
   00000010 5d00 00c3
   00000015
```

and when I printf the buffer and buffer2 I see

```
   55 48 89 e5 bf 00 00 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00 b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3 

   55 48 89 e5 bf 00 00 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00 b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3
```

which matches the output from hexdump. However when load buffer2 into my new section (I didn't include that part of the code), I used objdump -s -j .my_data foo and I see some other data not similar to the output above.

I apologize for the dumb question but I just want to confirm if the memcpy I used it's actually copying the data from buffer to buffer2 so I can discard this part and look for the error in the rest of my program. From the output of the second for loop I would think it is. I'm also using gcc, thanks.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdint.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   
   int main (){

   uint8_t buffer[21];
   uint8_t buffer2[21];
   FILE *ptr;
   ptr = fopen("binfile.bin", "rb");
   size_t file_size = 0;
   
   if(!ptr)
   {
     printf("unable to open file");
     return 1;
   }

   fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_END);
   file_size = ftell(ptr); 
   rewind(ptr);

   int i = 0;
   
   fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, ptr);
   memcpy(buffer2, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

   for(i = 0; i < 21; i++)
   {
    printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
   }

   printf("\n\n");
   for(i = 0; i < 21; i++)
   {
    printf("%02x ", buffer2[i]);
   }

   fclose(ptr);
  
   return 0;

   }
```

Comment: `fread(buffer, file_size, 1, ptr);` (you should check `file_size <= sizeof buffer`) You should `memcpy` that many bytes too, and only loop that many. You invoke *Undefined Behavior* reading `buffer[20]` when `buffer[19]` is the last initialized element. Otherwise, why are you calling `file_size = ftell(ptr);` if you don't use that information?

Comment: you should also change ` for(i = 0; i < 21; i++)` to ` for(i = 0; i < sizeof buffer2; i++)`

Comment: "...which matches the output from hexdump" ... I don't see 48 in your hexdump.

Comment: one more thing 
when using `printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);`  you should use `buffer[i] & 0xff`

Comment: @yano sorry I copied the output by hand since I'm using a VM, but it matches the output.

Comment: Yes, `memcpy` is copying the entire `buffer` to `buffer2` and invoking *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to copy bytes that are not initialized (indeterminate). Since you are using a fixed buffer, you can eliminate `fseek`, `ftell` and `rewind` and simply use `size_t nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ptr);` and the number of bytes read will be returned when the `size` parameter to `fread` is `1`.

Comment: did you hand copy 3 extra bytes too? Hexdump outputs 18 bytes, yet your buffers print out 21. In fact, that can't be the full output from hexdump, you're missing two bytes on the first line. Far more difficult to help when the question has erroneous information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking right as far as how you are approaching copying `buffer` to `buffer2`, but you are failing to ensure you only attempt to access the elements of `buffer` that are validly initialized. Since your file contains only `20` bytes, when you attempt to access `buffer[20]` you are attempting to access a variable with *automatic storage duration* while the value is *indeterminate* invoking *Undefined Behavior*. All bets are off.

You can handle this by fully initializing `buffer`, e.g.

```
uint8_t buffer[21] = {0);
```

which if you fill less than all elements with `fread` is still okay because all elements are validly initialized.

The other way is simply to read with the `size` parameter to `fread` set at `1` so `fread` returns the number of bytes read. Then you can use that value to output your results, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* max number of characters (bytes) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    size_t nbytes = 0;
    unsigned char buf1[MAXC] = {0}, buf2[MAXC] = {0};
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "rb") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    nbytes = fread (buf1, 1, MAXC, fp);     /* with size=1, no. of bytes returned */
    
    if (fp != stdin)                        /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    memcpy (buf2, buf1, nbytes);            /* copy nbytes buf1, buf2 */
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; i++)     /* outuput buf1 contents */
        printf (" %02x", buf1[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; i++)     /* output buf2 contents */
        printf (" %02x", buf2[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `dat/bytes20.bin`, you would receive:

```
$ ./bin/fread_bytes dat/bytes20.bin
 44 55 e5 89 00 bf 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00 b8 5d 00 00 c3
 44 55 e5 89 00 bf 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00 b8 5d 00 00 c3
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Actually both answers worked, I noticed I defined buffer & buffer2 inside a function that's called by main. i.e int foo (int foo2, int foo3){ buffer[21]= {0}; buffer2[21]= {0}; ... } I would printf the output fime but when I opened my my_data section I would see random data but when I moved buffer & buffer as global variables it worked fine for both answers.

Comment: Ah, so you were attempting to output the contents of arrays declared local to a function. Any array declared local (inside) a function (unless declared `static`) only survives for the life of the function and is invalidated upon function return. You can dynamically allocate, declare as `static` or use a global (not recommended) and have the data survive return. Glad you got it working. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

here is the corrected code: note the & 0xFF when printing

```
uint8_t buffer[21];
uint8_t buffer2[21];
FILE *ptr;
ptr = fopen("binfile.bin", "rb");
size_t file_size = 0;

if (!ptr)
{
    printf("unable to open file");
    return 1;
}

fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_END);
file_size = ftell(ptr);
rewind(ptr);

int i = 0;

fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, ptr);
memcpy(buffer2, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

for (i = 0; i < sizeof buffer; i++)
{
    printf("%02x ", buffer[i] & 0xFF);
}

printf("\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < sizeof buffer2; i++)
{
    printf("%02x ", buffer2[i] & 0xFF);
}

fclose(ptr);

return 0;
```

here is the output

```
55 48 89 e5 bf 00 00 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00 b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3

55 48 89 e5 bf 00 00 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00 b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3
```